# JSON sending data from Android to PHP webservice

Tags: android, json

The code below is the codes in my Android application where did I did wrongly?

```
Button btnUpdate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUpdate);

    // button click event
    btnUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            for (String aReceiver : params) {
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("receiverid[]", receiver));
            }
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userid", args[0]));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("timestart", args[1]));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("timeend", args[2]));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("amount", args[3]));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pdate", args[4]));
            //params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("receiverid[]", args[5]));

            JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(URL, "POST", params);
```

The line : for (String receiver : **receiver**) {

the **receiver** variable is giving me a red line. I copied the code online, and it does not have much details. How should I declare the variable?

Comment: `for (String r : receiver)` , any name but the name of the iterated `List`..

Comment: @MohammedAoufZOUAG Okay,this is one point. 

You were saying List. I think you are referring to this?

**List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();**

So I am suppose to replace **receiver** with **params** ?

Comment: Post the full code, where you declare the `receiver` list.

Comment: @MohammedAoufZOUAG I have updated the code in the question. Please help me take a look ya :)

Comment: What error do you still get ?

Comment: @MohammedAoufZOUAG the line in the **for** loop has a problem, **Cannot resolve symbol 'receiver'**.

Answer (score 0):

Your iterator and the collection you loop through have the same name. This is not allowed.

You can try something like:

```
for (String aReceiver : receiver) {
  // your code
}
```

Comment: Thank you! but I can't upvote your answer or the guy above because I only have 11 rep.